# Clearing Html textbox value permanently using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName)%>`. Here I'm checking wheather user name is available or not. If it's not available then I need to clear the TextBox. I used the query `$("#UserName").val("");`. But after the event completion again the text box getting the value. Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:** Additional Javascript code from comments:

```
function CheckAvailability() {
    $.post("/WebTeamReleaseDB/CheckAvailability", {
        Username: $("#UserName").val()
    }, function(data) {
        var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
        var newid = myObject;
        if (newid == 1) {
            $("#usernamelookupresult").html("<font color='green'>Available :-D</font>")
        } else {
            $("#UserName").val("");
            $("#usernamelookupresult").html("<font color='red'>Taken :-(</font>")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the element's id `UserName`?

Comment: Could you post a little more code?

Comment: I'm using Html.TextBoxFor(). Here how can I use the element id?

Comment: function CheckAvailability() {
$.post("/WebTeamReleaseDB/CheckAvailability",
{Username: $("#UserName").val()},function (data) {    var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');var newid = myObject;if (newid == 1) { $("#usernamelookupresult").html("<font color='green'>Available :-D</font>")} else {$("#UserName").val("");
$("#usernamelookupresult").html("<font color='red'>Taken :-(</font>")}});}

Comment: which event are you talking about?

Comment: @Dvir: I just want to clear the textbox value which I entered before calling the java script method.

Comment: @Andy: Ya its unique only. Since I'm directly binding with my model

Comment: You should edit your question and put the code there.

Comment: else{ $("#UserName").setval("");}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my problem.

HTML code:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName,new { @onchange="CheckAvailability()" }) %>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function CheckAvailability() {
        var value;
        if (document.getElementById("UserName").value == "") {
            $("#usernamelookupresult").html("");
            alert("Please Enter User Name");
        }
        else {
            $.post("/WebTeamReleaseDB/CheckAvailability",
            {
                Username: $("#UserName").val()
            },
                function (data) {
                    var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
                    var newid = myObject;
                    value = myObject;
                    if (newid == 1) {
                        $("#usernamelookupresult").html("<font color='green'>Available :-D</font>")
                    }
                    else if (newid == 2) {
                        $("#usernamelookupresult").html("<font color='red'>UserName Invalid! :-(</font>")
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#usernamelookupresult").html("<font color='red'>Taken :-(</font>")
                        $("#UserName").val("");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName)%>`, it may be rendering to the page as `<input name="UserName">`, so `$("#UserName").val("");` is not finding it, as there is no id="UserName".

One possible solution: use `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName, new { id = "UserName" })%>`, which should render to the page as `<input name="UserName" id="UserName">`.  After that, `$("#UserName").val("");` should work, since the textbox now has that id attribute.

Comment: I have tried ur code also. But its its clearing the textbox until the java script event completes its execution. After execution completes, textbox getting the value.

Comment: @Davis: I got it Davis. I have written like this: <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName, new { @onchange=CheckAvailability()}